# Do all derived classes from a hierarchy require access to the virtual base class?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-inheritance

When I try to compile the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int v) : virt(v) { }
    int virt;
    int getVirt(void) const { return virt; }
};

class B : private virtual A {
protected:
    B(int v) : A(v) { }
    using A::getVirt;
};

class C : public B, private virtual A {
protected:
    C(int v) : A(v), B(v) { }
    using A::getVirt;
};

class D : public C {
public:
    D(void) : C(3) { }
    using C::getVirt;
};

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    D d;
    std::cout << "The number is: " << d.getVirt() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error about D not instantiating A; is that correct?  If a virtual base is embedded in the hierarchy do all derived classes also need to derive from that base, virtually, so they can call the parametric constructor of the virtual base?

BTW, here are the errors produced by G++:

```
Main.cpp: In constructor ‘D::D()’:
Main.cpp:22:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
Main.cpp:22:18: note: candidates are:
Main.cpp:3:5: note: A::A(int)
Main.cpp:3:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Main.cpp:1:7: note: A::A(const A&)
Main.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: which version of g++?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use private virtual inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kerrek SB mentions, you *need* to initialize `A` in the constructor for `D`.

However, you must also explicitly  tell the compiler that you are **not** accessing `A` from its (privately) derived context by using the scope operator.

```
class D : public C {
public:
    D(void) : ::A(3), C(3) { }
//            ^^ Access this constructor from a global context
    using C::getVirt;
};
```

This also means that your constructor must be public, as is already the case with your code.

Comment: +1 Very interesting, it compiles after making this change, but I don't understand how using the scope resolution operator changes the fact that `A` is being inherited privately.

Comment: That could get complicated if A is in a namespace hierarchy.

Comment: @TimeHorse Yes, you would have to match that namespace hierarchy if so.

Comment: @Praetorian it's an unusual syntax.  Considering the object and the constructor separately, the object is still private while the required constructor is now accessed as `A::A(int)` instead of the default `D::C::A::A(int)`

Comment: +1 Very nice. The interesting point seems to be the *name lookup* that ensues by mentioning `A` in the initializer (cf. 12.6.2/2). Names within the scope of the constructor's class come first, and only then are names from the ambient scope considered. Adding scope resolution gets the "right" path to the class.

Answer (score 6):

That has nothing to do with access control (at least not primarily). Rather, you have to understand how virtual bases work: The virtual base subobject is initialized by the *most derived* class. Since you don't mention `A` in the constructor initializer list of `D`, the default constructor is tried, but doesn't exist.

To fix this, initalize `A` properly in `D`:

```
 D() : A(3), C(3) { }
```

When you say `A(3)`, name lookup is performed according to 12.6.2/2:

> In a *mem-initializer-id* an initial unqualified identifier is looked up in the scope of the constructor’s class and, if not found in that scope, it is looked up in the scope containing the constructor’s definition.

As Drew Dorman rightly points out, you can force a direct path to the virtual base class by calling it `::A` and thus obtaining the desired access.

Comment: It won't compile if only change constructor of D, I tried the changed code in C++, it reports: error: `class A' is inaccessible. Mostly because private inheritance is used between class A and B,C. So I guess it does have something to do with access control.

Comment: @SongWang: OK, fair enough, but indirectly so. It appears that the virtual base can only be private if it's default-constructible.

Comment: I choose this answer as confirmation of my theory, so the solution is as follows, for all derived classes D (annoyingly):

    `class D : public C, private virtual A {
    public:
        D(void) : A(3), C(3) { }
        using C::getVirt;
    };`